# How to filter questions with particular tags

Tags: support, tags

Can I filter the questions with particular tags from the Questions list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the search filtering that Flow mentions, you can also set up "favorite" and "ignored" tags from the right sidebar on [the main page](https://android.stackexchange.com/). Ignored tags will be faded grey on the question lists and favorited ones will be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is a bit reliable than search filtering.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, simply enter [tag] as search option. It's also stated [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=).

For example, if you want to search for all questions tagged [samsung-galaxy-s](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-s), you would enter [samsung-galaxy-s] in the search field: [Result](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-s)

Comment: and what if i want to exclude all question with this tag?

Comment: If you want to exclude an tag, add an minus sign ("-") before the [tag]. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24514/how-do-i-combine-exclude-multiple-tags-from-a-search