# What are "tags", and how can I use them most effectively?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

What are "tags"? Is there any good advice on how one can use them on *Android Enthusiasts* in the most effective way?

Answer (score 1):

### What is a tag?

Basically, a [tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_tag) is an index term assigned to a piece of information. We use tags to organize the content on our site, and to make it easier to find information. You may think of "tags" as being "categories"

### Use tags to find your answer before asking your question

Tags help you to filter the huge amount of information present on this site. The search box available on each page also includes the possibility to [filter by tags](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/831/how-to-filter-questions-with-particular-tags) (and keywords, at the same time).

Many tags also have a good tag wiki, often containing some "first aid". So if you find some tags matching your issue, make sure to check their tag wikis. They are reachable e.g. via the 'info' link on the mouse-over popup, or the 'more info...' link when listing all questions of a certain tag.

### What tags are available?

To see what tags are available, you can use the [tags tab](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags), and have all available tags listed. You can order this list by [most popular](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular), by [name](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name), or by [time added](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new). An input box on top of the tags page also allows you to filter tags.

### How should I use tags with my questions?

Best use is conform to what described in "What is a tag?" above: tags should not repeat your question, but rather categorize it. You can use up to 5 tags with each question. While you start typing in the "tag" input field, the system starts suggesting tags containing the input string.

Chose wisely: do not "blindly select", but at least check the "tag wiki excerpt" in the popup when hovering your mouse over the tag. Use [device tags](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-we-discourage-phone-model-tags-in-non-phone-specific-questions) and Android version tags only when they are relevant *to your issue*. See also: [How can I tag my question in the most effective way?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-can-i-tag-my-question-in-the-most-effective-way)

### Related questions

- [How to filter questions with particular tags](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/831/how-to-filter-questions-with-particular-tags)
- [Should we discourage phone model tags in non-phone-specific questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-we-discourage-phone-model-tags-in-non-phone-specific-questions)
- [How can I tag my question in the most effective way?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-can-i-tag-my-question-in-the-most-effective-way)

### Further readings

- [Knowledge tag (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_tag)